# In C language, comparing 2 members of a structure

Tags: c, struct, compare

I seem to have trouble with comparing 2 members of a structure.
I can see in watch window that the sequence in all logs are 0x000.

This one evaluates AllLogsNotZero to TRUE

```
for (i=0;(i<(3)&&(!AllLogsNotZero));i++)
   {
       UINT8 j;
       j=i+1;
       UINT16* comp1;
       UINT16* comp2;
       comp1 = (UINT16*) (&Data.log[i].Sequence);
       comp2 = (UINT16*) (&Data.log[j].Sequence);
       if ((Data.log[i].Sequence == Data.log[j].Sequence) == 0)
            AllLogsNotZero=FALSE;
       else
            AllLogsNotZero=TRUE;
```

This one evaluates AllLogsNotZero to FALSE

```
for (i=0;(i<(3)&&(!AllLogsNotZero));i++)
   {
       UINT8 j;
       j=i+1;
       UINT16* comp1;
       UINT16* comp2;
       comp1 = (UINT16*) (&Data.log[i].Sequence);
       comp2 = (UINT16*) (&Data.log[j].Sequence);
       if (Data.log[i].Sequence == Data.log[j].Sequence)
            AllLogsNotZero=FALSE;
       else
            AllLogsNotZero=TRUE;
```

I don't know why.

Comment: Since you're not using either `comp1` or `comp2` in the comparison code you're asking about, you should remove those lines (4 of them) from each snippet — that's the 'minimal' part of creating an MCVE ([MCVE]).  It is a good idea to make your code into an MCVE.  It's also worth using `UINT8 j = i + 1;` to initialize the variable, rather than using two lines.  (Similar comments apply to `comp1` and `comp2`, too.)

Comment: What is the initial value of `AllLogsNotZero` _before_ the 2 loops?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're making a mountain out of a molehill.  I think the way I'd write the loop using your current variable name is:

```
bool AllLogsNotZero = true;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if (Data.log[i].Sequence == 0)
    {
        AllLogsNotZero = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (AllLogsNotZero)
    …processing option for no zero logs
else
    …processing option for at least one log zero
```

We can debate whether the loop limit should be 3 or 4 (or some other value); it isn't entirely clear from your code, but you set `j` to `i+1` and use that, and limit `i` to `< 3`, so when the code doesn't use `i+1`, the limit should probably be 4.  It would be better to have an enumeration or `#define` value for the limit — the name would indicate what you're measuring against better than just the number.

The negative in the name (`AllLogsNotZero`) also makes life harder; avoid that when you can.  For example:

```
bool LogsZero = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if (Data.log[i].Sequence == 0)
    {
        LogsZero = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (LogsZero)
    …processing option for at least one log zero
else
    …processing option for no zero logs
```

Answer (score 2):

Look if statements

First check:

```
//You check if they are the same
if (Data.log[i].Sequence == Data.log[j].Sequence)
```

Second check

```
//You check if they are not the same
if ((Data.log[i].Sequence == Data.log[j].Sequence) == 0)

//Can be evaluated as:
if (Data.log[i].Sequence != Data.log[j].Sequence)
```

Comment: But I have to check the members, Data.log[1].Sequence and Data.log[2].Sequence to make sure all of them are 0! hence my code has the number 0 in it.

Comment: @newb7777 please understand that `if ((Data.log[i].Sequence == Data.log[j].Sequence) == 0)` is not checking if any/all data values are `0`. It is checking the result of the comparison, regardless of the actual data values. The comparison `Data.log[i].Sequence == Data.log[j].Sequence` evaluates to `1` or `0` to show whether the data are equal, or not equal.

Comment: @Weather Vane, I see your point, the struct member compares result to each other and in the case it is not equal it evaluates to 0. else it evaluates to a **non zero number** (?). I see why comparing the non zero number result to 0 is always `FALSE`.

Comment: It specifically evaluates to `1`. Unlike some C library functions which return `0` or `non 0` (such as `strcmp`).

Comment: ... and which does not mean `false` or `true`. It is pointless comparing the comparison, as this answer says.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0;(i<(3)&&(!AllLogsNotZero));i++)
   {
       UINT16 Var1 = 0;

       if (Data.log[i].Sequence == Var1)
            AllLogsNotZero=FALSE;
       else
            AllLogsNotZero=TRUE;
```

This works!!

Comment: What's the benefit of using `Var1` rather than simply writing `if (Data.log[i].Sequence == 0)`?

Comment: Agreed, I thought it was important to have the variable as a 16 bit number compare so i defined it but you are correct, it doesn't make a difference,